# Simplifying the expression $(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})/(\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{14}+\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{21})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, factoring

Alrite guys, this question might sound stupid, but I can't find a way to simplify this complicated expression:

$$\frac{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{14}+\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{21}}$$

I can't take the conjugate, nor I can factor the bottom.

Any help or hints?

Comment: Can't factor the bottom?

Comment: Just a nitpick; this is a number and not a polynomial.

Comment: This is not "combinatorics" ... btw, and "roots"?

Comment: This solution depends on the problem solver noticing that $(10, 14) = 2(5, 7)$ and $15, 21) = 3(5, 7)$. If the denominator had been written $\sqrt{21}+\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{14}+\sqrt{10}$, the solution would have been harder to find. If the denominator had been $\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{14}+\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{21}$, the problem would be quite hard. I'm not sure how good a problem this is, in terms of what it really teaches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{14}+\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{21}$$

$$=\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})+\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})$$

$$=(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$$

Can you take it from here?